# Count of related records in many-to-many relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I am trying to buit a classmethod, which returns number of members associated with a project. I tried:

```
# method of class Project
@classmethod
def member_count(cls, project_id):
   return Session.query(ProjectMember).\
            filter(ProjectMember.project_id==project_id).count()
```

The many-to-many relationship is defined as:

```
class Member(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'member'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    login = Column(String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    project_list = relationship("ProjectMember", backref="member")

class Project(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'project'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)

class ProjectMember(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'project_member'
    project_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("project.id"), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    member_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("member.id"), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    project = relationship("Project", backref = "project_member")
    is_pm = Column(Boolean, default = True, nullable = False)
    UniqueConstraint('project_id', 'member_id')
```

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you try to execute the method? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 4):

Either use a simple property like below, which will use the current session of the instance to get count of children

```
class Project(...):
    # ...
    @property
    def member_count_simple(self):
       return object_session(self).query(ProjectMember).with_parent(self).count()


print(my_proj.member_count_simple) # @note: will issue an SQL statement
```

or use [`Hybrid Attribute`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/hybrid.html):

```
class Project(Base):
    # ...

    @hybrid_property
    def member_count(self):
        return object_session(self).query(ProjectMember).with_parent(self).count()

    @member_count.expression
    def _member_count_expression(cls):
        q = select([func.count(ProjectMember.project_id)]).\
                where(ProjectMember.project_id == cls.id).\
                label("member_count")
        return q
```

... in which case you can use this expression in your query (`filter`s and `order_by`, for example):

```
qry = (session.query(Project, Project.member_count)
        .order_by(Project.member_count.desc())
        )
# @note: it returns tuples (Project, member_count)
for (proj, cnt_mem) in qry.all():
    print(proj.name, cnt_mem)
```

Comment: van, where does `object_session(self).` come from?

Comment: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.object_session