# Count number of SQLAlchemy relationships inside a filter

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've been trying to google this but I'm only really coming up with how to retrieve the count rather than filter by it. The closest result I found was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25118256/2403000), but I'm constructing the query without a session so using `object_session` raises `UnmappedInstanceError`.

Given `Parent` and `Child` models, connected by `Parent.children`, how could I query which parents have a certain amount of children?

I've tried `session.query(Parent).filter(func.count(Parent.children)>1)`, but it complains about misuse of the `count` function.

As I'm building the query recursively for a search function, the query is actually built up of dozens of filters, so if at all possible I'd like this to remain in a single filter.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this might work (not at all tested)

```
session.query(func.count(Children.parent_id))\
    .group_by(Children.parent_id)\
    .filter(func.count(Children.parent_id) > 5)
```

Comment: Thanks, though I'm wanting to query which parents have a certain amount of children, rather than querying a single parent (correct me if I'm wrong but doesn't the above query have the same effect as `len(parent.children) > 5`?). I believe I need the equivalent of `WHERE (SELECT count(*) from Children where Children.parent_id == Parent.row_id) > 5`, and SQLAlchemy is only doing `WHERE count(Children.parent_id == Parent.row_id) > 5` if I print out my query. I'm not very good at SQL but I assume the issue could be down to that. I tried joining `Children` and tested a few `group_by`'s but no luck.

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out after typing up that comment :)

Answer (score 0):

After comparing the generated SQL with what is actually needed, I noticed it needed a nested select statement, which can be done with `sqlalchemy.select`.

Instead of this:

```
session.query(Parent).filter(func.count(Parent.children)>1)
```

The correct syntax is this:

```
subsearch = select([func.count(Parent.children)]).where(Parent.row_id==Child.parent_id).as_scalar()
session.query(Parent).filter(subsearch>1)
```